# Unable to pray on time at work?

Tags: salat, work, prayer-timings

As-salamu alaikum, I work as a security guard and most times work long hours of 10/11 and the odd one day of 6.5 hours. I am able to take one 30min break to pray my zhur. However unable to take the other 30min for magrib. Which then leaves me with no asr mag  on time. Due to their rules of not allowing 15 min breaks for prayer and using my own to break it up with. What should I do? As there is no other job opportunities for me at the moment. Should I use toilet break as my prayer break? Or try to explain it would only take 5min to pray as I’m sure you can cut down to praying fard only? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can combine two prayers. i.e. You can pray Asr immediately after the Zuhr prayer.

> Noteworthy is that there is no difference amongst all the Islamic
> schools of thought, the ahl al-qibla, in allowing the combination of
> the two obligatory prayers; al-zuhr and al-`asr, at` Arafa [ground
> which is included in the rites of ‘Hajj’ (the Pilgrimage to Mecca,
> Saudi Arabia)] at the time of the noon (al-zuhr) prayer. Technically,
> this is [called] ‘jam' al-taqdim’ (the preceding combination).
> Similarly, there is no difference between them in allowing the
> combination of the two obligatory [prayers] - al-maghrib and al-`isha'
>
> - at al-Muzdalifa [another ground near Mecca, Saudi Arabia] at the time of the `isha' [prayers].
>
> Technically, this is called ‘jam' al-ta'khir’ (the delayed
> combination). There is no difference [amongst the scholars] in
> preferring these two combinations. Indeed, they are amongst the
> prophetic practices. However, they (the scholars) have differed as to
> the permissibility of combining the prayers in daily performances.

[Referene](https://www.al-islam.org/questions-jurisprudence-abd-al-husayn-sharaf-al-din-al-musawi/chapter-one-combining-two-prayers)