# I can't pray zhur in school

Tags: school

I am going to a school in UAE called sabis,I asked the aqc and I asked the other higher-ups, but they told me the same thing the director said students can pray after school,  5 minutes before aser comes, surprisingy most people I asked were Muslims but they said they can't extend the time the break or give a small period of time where Muslim students can pray. The only days I have problem with is Wednesday and Thursday because the break ends at 12:30 and the school day continues until 3:30, but on Monday and Tuesday the break ends at 1:20. I don't know what to do, If i pray without someone's permission I get in trouble, what do I do? And how can I get help?

Comment: does the combination of zuhr and asr prayer solves your problem? https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/81300/67